# Ruby's bitwise shift operator "<<" confusion in conjuction with array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am studying Ruby and can't figure this out. I have an exercise where I have to add a method into a Library class which contains games. Each game is an instance of a class Game. So the solution is the following:

```
class Library
  attr_accessor :games

  def initialize(games)
    self.games = games
  end

  def has_game?(search_game)
    for game in games
      return true if game == search_game
    end
    false
  end

  def add_game(game)
    @games << game
  end
end
```

I can't understand how `<<` works in this case. Is this a bitwise left shift? Does Library class just assumes that `games` is an array, I believe I can pass anything to the Library class when I am initialising, single game or an array of games?

Comment: I guess `games` is some kind of collection where `<<` is rather the *add to collection* operation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you have:

```
@games << game
```

`<<` is actually a method. If it is a method, you ask, why isn't it written in the normal way:

```
@games.<<(game)
```

? You could, in fact, write it that way and it would work fine. Many Ruby methods have names that are symbols. A few others are `+`, `-`, `**`, `&`, `||` and `%`. Ruby knows you'd prefer writing `2+3` instead of `2.+(3)`, so she let's you do the former (and then quietly converts it to the latter). This accommodation is often referred to as "syntactic sugar".

`<<` is one of `@games`' *methods* (and `game` is `<<`'s argument), because `@games` is the *receiver* of the method `<<` (technically `:<<`). Historically, it's called the "receiver" because with OOP you "send" the method to the receiver.

To say that `<<` is a method of `@games` means that `<<` is an *instance method* of `@games`'s class. Thus, we have:

```
@games.methods.include?(:<<) #=> true
@games.class.instance_methods.include?(:<<) #=> true
```

I expect `@games` is an instance of the class `Array`. `Array`'s instance methods are listed [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html). For example:

```
@games = [1,2,3]
@games.class     #=> [1,2,3].class => Array
@games << 4      #=> [1,2,3,4]
@games.<<(5)     #=> [1,2,3,4,5]
```

On the other hand, suppose `@games` were an instance of `Fixnum`. For example:

```
@games = 7
@games.class     #=> 7.class => Fixnum
```

which in binary looks like this:

```
@games.to_s(2)   #=> "111"
```

Then:

```
@games << 2      #=> 28
28.to_s(2)       #=> "11100"
```

because `<<` is an instance method of the class [Fixnum](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html).

As a third example, suppose `@games` were a hash:

```
@games = { :a => 1 }
@games.class     #=> { :a => 1 }.class => Hash
```

Then:

```
@games << { :b => 2 }
  #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' for {:a=>1}:Hash
```

The problem is clear from the error message. The class [Hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html) has no instance method `<<`.

One last thing: consider the method [Object#send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-send). Recall that, at the outset, I said that methods are sent to receivers. Instead of writing:

```
@games = [1,2,3]
@games << 4         #=> [1,2,3,4]
```

you could write:

```
@games.send(:<<, 4) #=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

This is how you should think of methods and receivers. Because `send` is an instance method of the class `Object`, and all objects inherit `Object`'s instance methods, we see that `send` is "sending" a method (`:<<`, which can alternatively be expressed as a string, `"<<"`) and its arguments (here just `4`) to the receiver.

There are times, incidentally, when you *must* use `send` to invoke a method. For one, `send` works with `private` and `protected` methods. For another, you can use `send` when you want to invoke a method dynamically, where the name of the method is the value of a variable.

In sum, to understand what `method` does in:

```
receiver.method(*args)
```

look for the doc for the instance method `method` in `receiver`'s class. If you Google "ruby array", for example, the first hit will likely be the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html) for the class `Array`.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a bitwise left shift, it's "shovel" operator. You, probably, know that in Ruby operators are implemented as methods, i.e. when you write

```
1 + 1
```

what is actually going on:

```
1.+(1)
```

The same is true for "shovel" (`<<`) operator, it's just a [method on `Array`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C) class, that appends its arguments to the end of the array and returns the array itself, so it can be chained:

```
>> arr = []
=> []
>> arr << 1
=> [1]
>> arr
=> [1]
>> arr << 2 << 3
=> [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `@games` is an array. The shift operator for an array adds an element to the end of the array, similar to `array#push`.

> ary << obj → ary
>
> Append—Pushes the given object on to the end of this array. This expression returns the array itself, so several appends may be chained together.